# C possible memory leak? Crashes

Tags: c, memory, hashtable, hash-function

I'm trying to build my own little hashtable library for fun. (In C)

I hope it's not too trivial for you: i'm stuck with my program crashing due to a possible memory leak.
The problem is in a function i wrote to release all the memory allocated to the table when needed.

```
void destroy_table(struct elem* table, int len){              //releases the memory allocated to the table
int i;
for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    struct elem* temp = table+i;
    do{

        struct elem* e = temp->ptr;
        // printf("sono qui!\n");
        free(temp->str);   // <-- the program crashes here.
        free(temp);
        temp = e;
    }while(temp != NULL);
}}
```

the table is an array of struct elements but it can happen two elements have the same index. In that case a list is built in that element.

This is the struct i use to build up the array:

```
struct elem{
char* str;
struct elem* ptr;};
```

I've read the guidelines so i won't post much code. But i initialized the struct array with all empty strings for str and NULL values for the pointers.

Comment: Does it crash on the second iteration?  Shouldn't `temp` be set to `e->ptr` at the end of the loop block?

Comment: Is `temp->ptr->str` `NULL`?

Comment: Fiddling Bits no it crashes on the first.

Comment: if your strings are not dynamic allocated, they should not be released, e.g. `free("ciao")` will crash.

Comment: You need a `while` loop instead of a `do-while` loop.

Comment: GoodDeeds no it shouldn't. Because the last element of the list has str = "" and ptr = NULL. so the last iteration has str defined

Comment: So i don't need to release them at all or should i dinamically allocate them

Answer (score 0):

I seems like you are initializing your char* with string literals like that :

```
char *str = "";
```

String literals in C are not allocated from the heap, they get there own memory space in the program, and stay there for the entire program lifetime, even if `str` goes out of scope.

That is why you shouldn't attempt to free a `char*` that is a string literal. Instead, you should initialize your `str` to `NULL` and allocate them on the heap as you need. You could then use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to populate your strings.